# Understanding *[] in python passed to .agg() in pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I am trying to understand how the *[] allows me to pass parameters to this 
aggregate in pyspark. This runs, but I am trying to reuse the code in another example and was hoping someone could point me to the appropriate documentation so that I knew what was going on here. I like that it can pass the columns in the list as a parameter.

I was hoping that either someone knew what *[] is doing here.
How does it know to append a column  to the DataFrame and not just iterate through the list, and execute once for each element in testdata.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
testdata= spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 144.5, 5.9, 33, 'M'),
    (2, 167.2, None, 45, 'M'),
    (3, 124.1, 5.2, 23, 'F'),
    (4, None, 5.9, None, 'M'),
    (5, 133.2, 5.7, 54, 'F'),
    (3, 124.1, None, None, 'F'),
    (5, 129.2, 5.3, None, 'M'),
    ],
    ['id', 'weight', 'height', 'age', 'gender']
)
testdata.where(
        fn.col("gender") == 'M'
    ).select(
        '*'
    ).agg(*[
        (1 - (fn.count(c) / fn.count('*'))).alias(c + '_missing')
        for c in testdata.columns
    ]).toPandas()
```

output:

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
|id_missing|weight_missing|height_missing|age_missing|gender_missing|
+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
|       0.0|          0.25|          0.25|        0.5|           0.0|
+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Also if someone could please provide feedback for why they down voted this, I would appreciate it. Being new to the community it is helpful for me to learn what to not do.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I imagine because the code was initially not well-formatted, and your question is more on the side of "please explain this output" and less on the side of "expected X, got Y, tried this, how do I get X". See the help center article on [types of questions to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). I think this falls under 'inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”'.

Comment: I will strive to state things in a more objective manner, I appreciate the clarification surrounding the ambiguity of my question.

Answer (score 4):

Using `*` in front of a `list` expands out the members as individual arguments. So, the following two function calls will be equivalent:

```
my_function(*[1, 2, 3])
my_function(1, 2, 3)
```

Obviously, the first one is not very useful if you already know the precise number of arguments. It becomes more useful with a comprehension like you are using, where is is not clear how many items will be in the `list`.

Comment: Usaually .agg() would just return a single output, so if i use *[]  how does it know to column bind the results?

Comment: Because you are passing in all the columns.